# Convert Java to Kotlin (With a function as an argument)

Tags: kotlin

I want this code in Kotlin:

```
public class LobbySwitcherGui extends AGUI
{
    public LobbySwitcherGui()
    {
        super(27, "someTitle");

        setItem(0, new ItemStack(Material.NETHER_STAR), player -> {
            player.sendMessage("Some message");
        });
    }
}
```

but if I convert it in IntellIJ its doesnt work for me.

```
class LobbySwitcherGui : AGUI(27, "someTitle")
{
    init {
        setItem(0, ItemStack(Material.NETHER_STAR), { player -> player.sendMessage("Some message") })
    }
}
```

The last Argument istn working and I cant fix it..

AGUI class is this: https://ghostbin.com/paste/gjdzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kotlin can create Runnables and Function, BiFunction, etc that way.. 
you seem to create something called a `YourGUIAction`, check if that might be replaced with `action: (Player) -> Unit`
or in general `(ArgumentTypes) -> ReturnType`

Comment: But I also need to run this code after this. I was doing that with: https://ghostbin.com/paste/x2cq4 I saved the Unit in a HashMap. Now I just need to execute that

Comment: i do not think you saved the Unit.. that might be confusion, Unit in kotlin is like void in java, just a way to tell you there is no return value
if you mean the action is of type `(Player) -> Unit` or similar then you can call it like that and it should work fine

Comment: But I did save it in a hashmap     val actions: MutableMap<Int, (Player) -> Unit> BUT HOW do I call it

Comment: this may be useful: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html
you call it (probably) like so: `map[key]!!(player)` or `val action = map[key]!!`, because get on a map returns a nullable and then call the action with `action(player)`

Comment: works for meee thank you so much ^^ I need to learn so much about this, because I really want to write better code

Comment: @Nikky Please don't use `!!`. Do something like `action?.invoke(player)`, otherwise you'll risk a null pointer.

Comment: i agree, that would have been cleaner, i just wanted to show thats where the error was, the nullable, @zLucPlayZ please heed that advice, !! is generally very crude nullhandling
better is to use safe cal operators or checking via `if(action != null` and using smart  casting